# multidimensional scaling in r with corpus

Tags: r, corpus, mds

I would like to ask does anybody used MDS with corpus in R (not numerical data, but text)? 
If yes,
I would need technical help (usable script, Which function is followed the MDS scripts?

Thank you for the answer
Andrea

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking people for "technical help", while SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Does anybody else who has usable competence and experience in textmining in R and will ing to share it?